# i am doing project on cab fare prediction using python. while changing datetime column from object to datetime type

Tags: python, datetime

i am doing project on cab fare prediction using python. while changing datetime column from object to datetime type am getting an error. please help format looking like this: `2009-06-15 17:26:21 UTC`
i have tried below code

```
df_train["pickup_datetime"]= pd.to_datetime(df_train["pickup_datetime"], format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
```

```
ValueError: time data '43' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC' (match)
```

Comment: How does your dataframe looks like, how does your `pickup_datetime` looks like?

Comment: 2015-01-27 13:08:24 UTC its given in this format

Answer (score 1):

I am able to convert your datetime string without any issues using pandas module, there might be something else going on

```
import pandas as pd

li = ['2009-06-15 17:26:21 UTC', '2010-01-05 16:52:16 UTC', '2011-08-18 00:35:00 UTC', '2012-04-21 04:30:42 UTC', '2010-03-09 07:51:00 UTC',
 '2011-01-06 09:50:45 UTC', '2012-11-20 20:35:00 UTC', '2012-01-04 17:22:00 UTC']

df = pd.Series(li)
df = pd.to_datetime(df, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
print(df)
```

I get the output

```
0   2009-06-15 17:26:21
1   2010-01-05 16:52:16
2   2011-08-18 00:35:00
3   2012-04-21 04:30:42
4   2010-03-09 07:51:00
5   2011-01-06 09:50:45
6   2012-11-20 20:35:00
7   2012-01-04 17:22:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: if you look at the error its showing (time data '43' ) what it means can you suggest?

Comment: Can you run prinf(df) and show me how it looks like in the question? @DipuChouhan

Comment: pickup_datetime                                                                                                     
               2009-06-15 17:26:21 UTC           
                 2010-01-05 16:52:16 UTC         
               2011-08-18 00:35:00 UTC        
              2012-04-21 04:30:42 UTC           
               2010-03-09 07:51:00 UTC           
               2011-01-06 09:50:45 UTC        
               2012-11-20 20:35:00 UTC         
               2012-01-04 17:22:00 UTC

Comment: In the question please, not in the comments @DipuChouhan Also format the dataframe as well!

Comment: I was able to take your dataframe list and was able to use `pd.to_datetime` for all elements! Please check @DipuChouhan

Comment: Hi @DipuChouhan , if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to the answer, else please ask if you have any questions for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing the same project.
You have to use:

```py
df_train.drop(df_t[data['pickup_datetime'] == '43'].index,inplace=True).
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).